# how to get values from php multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can i get value of number and month from this array.

```
Array
(
   [mane] => Riya
   [id] => 70
   [order] => Array
     (
        [details] => Array
            (
                [number] => 4112
                [month] => March
            )

    )
```

)

Here is code which i had tried

```
foreach($order as $row) {
         echo $row['details']['number'];
         echo $row['details']['month'];            
    }
```

Comment: Use foreach with key value pair `foreach($order as $key => $value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
 foreach ($order['order'] as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value['number']."<BR />";
    echo $value['month']."<BR />";
}
```

**Here is a working [DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn$order%20=%20array%5Cn(%5Cn%20%22mane%22%20=%3E%20%22Riya%22,%5Cn%20%22id%22%20=%3E%2070,%5Cn%20%22order%22%20=%3E%20array%5Cn%20(%5Cn%20%22details%22%20=%3E%20array%5Cn%20(%5Cn%20%22number%22%20=%3E%204112,%5Cn%20%22month%22%20=%3E%20%22March%22%5Cn%20)%5Cn%5Cn%20)%5Cn);%5Cn%5Cnforeach%20($order['order']%20as%20$key%20=%3E%20$value)%5Cn%7B%5Cn%5Ctecho%20$value['number'].%22%3CBR%20/%3E%22;%5Cn%5Ctecho%20$value['month'].%22%3CBR%20/%3E%22;%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn?%3E%5Cn) for you**

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `order` array.

Change from

```
echo $row['details']['number'];
echo $row['details']['month'];
```

Into

```
echo $row['order']['details']['number'];
echo $row['order']['details']['month'];
//           ^ error was here.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
foreach($order as $key => $value){
    if( is_array($value) and !empty($value) ){
        foreach($value as $k => $v){
            printData($v['number']);    
            printData($v['month']);
        }
    }else{
        printData($value);  
    }   
}
```